# Dagger 2 injection of RecyclerView fails - cannot members inject raw type

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have a list adapter extended from `RecyclerView.Adapter`.  I am attempting to inject it using Dagger 2 but it fails with the error

```
Error:android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter has type parameters, cannot members inject the raw type. via:
ListAdapter
```

Salient file contents are as follows (non relevant lines deleted)

ListAdapter.java

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
  public ListAdapter(Context context) {
  }
```

ListFragment.java

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment {
    @Inject 
    ListAdapter listAdapter
}
```

InjectionModule.java

```
@Module
public class InjectionModule {
    @Provides
    ListAdapter provideLisAdapter(Context context) {
        return new ListAdapter(context);
    }
}
```

InjectionComponent.java

```
@Component (modules = InjectionModule.class)
public interface InjectionComponent {
    void inject(ListFragment listFragment);
}
```

I have googled extensively and found [this article](https://medium.com/@patrykpoborca/dagger-2-and-base-classes-generics-and-presenter-injection-7d82053080c#.yfqd9jxo9) and I think I am effectively using the superclass method mentioned half way down the article, but it's not working for me.  Hopefully somebody has managed to inject a RecyclerView.Adapter with Dagger 2 and if so, can share the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
@Component (modules = InjectionModule.class)
  public interface InjectionComponent {
  void inject(ListAdapter listAdapter);
}
```

with

```
@Component (modules = InjectionModule.class)
  public interface InjectionComponent {
  void inject(ListFragment listFragment);
}
```

Also, in order to construct ListAdapter object in your module, dagger should 
know where to find Context object. You can pass context in your module through constructor like this

```
@Module
public class InjectionModule {
Context context;
  public InjectionModule(Context context) {
      this.context = context;
   }

  @Provides
  ListAdapter provideLisAdapter() {
      return new ListAdapter(context);
  }
}
```

and then in your ListFragment inject your dependencies like this:

```
DaggerInjectionComponent.builder()
   .injectionModule(new InjectionModule(getActivity())
   .build()
   .inject(this);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Apologies -- I made a mistake when posing the question - my component interface does inject the `ListFragment` (typo), and my Module does supply the `Context` - I just didn't include that code for brevity.  I am doing what you propose and I get the `cannot members inject raw type` error.

Comment: I see when you define you adapter class you are not any providing ViewHolder as type argument. RecylerView.Adapter is a generic class with type argument as RecyclerView.ViewHolder. You should create a ViewHolder class and pass it in the adapter declaration, for e.g. public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<YourViewHolderClass>. Or for brevity sake you are not including code for this as well, in which case this answer would also be irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks - I've been away from this issue for a while, but your second comment was exactly right - I just had to explicitly specify the type of my ViewHolder in my ListAdapter class declaration.  Many thanks!